# JRuby Java Version Compatibility

Tags: java, version, jruby, java-7, java-5

we want to upgrade our JRuby application from 1.6 (with Java5) to 1.7 (with Java7).
I haven't found anywhere a support matrix or compatibility list. Does JRuby support any Java version out of the box?

bye,
selcuk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JRuby 1.7.0. Released](http://jruby.org/2012/10/22/jruby-1-7-0.html):

> Java 5 support dropped (Java 6+ required)

Bugs running under Java 8 are actively fixed (e.g. [#1899](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1899), [#1858](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1858)).

Comment: We use Java 7 with JRuby 1.7.12 - all things work fine.